# Can I use the Windows Mobile 6 SDK to develop Windows Mobile 5 Applications

Tags: windows-mobile, sdk

I would like to develop applications for a scanner running Windows Mobile 5.

The MSDN site says to download the latest SDK (the Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK). Will this work or should I download an earlier SDK for Windows Mobile 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CF there should be no problems. In the unmanaged world, you should just avoid the new features (sorry, i don't have a list) that are not in WM5